# How can i set all items of an array to 0 in GameMaker studio?

Tags: arrays, game-maker

Simple. I Need Help Setting All The Values Of An array to 0 in GameMaker: Studio. 
This is because i need to test if i have not modified the array by using

```
if array[id] != 0 {
//Enter code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, there are several ways, choose the best depending on the circumstances.

If you haven't filled anything in the array yet, adding a new item to a certain index initializes all previous values with "0":

```
var array;
array[length-1] = 0; //everything upto length-1 is filled
```

If you did already create the array and wish to reset it you should loop over it:

```
for (var i = array_get_length_1d(array) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    array[i] = 0;
}
```

If you do not care about the original memory locations, and you can create a complete new array, creating a new one in place of the old one can be slightly faster:

```
array = 0; //destroys the old array
array[length - 1] = 0; //recreates like in the first option
```